# Is there a built-in TypeConverter or UITypeEditor to edit a list of strings

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, windows-forms-designer, typeconverter

I wish to know if .Net-3.5 comes with a built-in `List<string>` or `string[]` `TypeConverter` or `UITypeEditor` so that I can edit this kind of property from a property grid.

Comment: Yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749542/icustomtypedescriptor-typedescriptionprovider-typeconverter-and-uitypeeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringArrayEditor, System.Design, [assembly version and public key token information here]", typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]

Comment: for sure it works with string[], I don't know if it works with List<string> but you can try..

Answer (score 5):

#### UITypeEditor for `List<String>`

For `string[]` you don't need to do anything special and the property grid will use a standard dialog containing a multi-line text box to edit string array and each line will be an element in the array.

To edit `List<string>` in property grid, you can use either of the following options:

- `StringCollectionEditor` which shows a dialog containing a multi-line text box to edit elements
- Create a custom `CollectionEditor` to edit items in a collection editor dialog

**Option 1 - StringCollectionEditor**

```
private List<string> myList = new List<string>();
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.StringCollectionEditor, " +
    "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<string> MyList {
    get {
        return myList;
    }
    set {
        myList = value;
    }
}
```

[image]

**Option 2 - Custom CollectionEditor**

First create the custom editor:

```
//You need to add reference to System.Design
public class MyStringCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor {
    public MyStringCollectionEditor() : base(type: typeof(List<String>)) { }
    protected override object CreateInstance(Type itemType) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then decorate the property with the editor attribute:

```
private List<string> myList = new List<string>();
[Editor(typeof(MyStringCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public List<string> MyList {
    get {
        return myList;
    }
    set {
        myList = value;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much!  Both suggestions work.  But there's still a couple of issues.  I'm uncomfortable with the hard-coded type name, but when I tried to use "typeof (StringCollectionEditor)" the compiler told me it was inaccessible due to its protection level.  And another website seemed to indicate it's obsolete.  The subclass of CollectionEditor worked nicely, but it's a bit cumbersome to use.  The StringCollectionEdtor is better from a user's perspective.  My ideal solution would be a custom editor.  I'm going to start playing with that now.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON `StringCollectionEditor` is internal and the way that I used it (using fully qualified name) is a completely standard solution.