# List<string> Property for populating a ComboBox inside a UserControl - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a UserControl with a ComboBox inside. I need to populate ComboBox items using a List property but I get the error below in designer:

`constructor on type 'system.string' not found`

and Here is my code:

```
public List<string> comboItems
{
    get
    {
        List<string> n = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in comboBox1.Items)
            n.Add(i.ToString());
        return n;
    }
    set
    {
        if (comboItems == null)
            comboItems = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in value)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me correctly

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: There is no error in lines, but when you try to add items to the list via visual studio properties window designer it will show the `constructor on type 'system.string' not found` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's not a good idea to expose items of the `ComboBox` as a `string[]` or as a `List<string>` because users may set `ComboItems[0] = "something"` but it will not change the first element of the combo box items.

But if you are looking for a solution to get rid of the error message which you receive in designer, instead of a `List<string>` use a `string[]` and change your code to:

```
public string[] ComboItems {
    get {
        return comboBox1.Items.Cast<object>()
                .Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
    }
    set {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(value);
    }
}
```

**Note**

This is the correct way of exposing `Items` property of a `ComboBox` in a `UserControl`:

```
[Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ListControlStringCollectionEditor, " +
    "System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
    typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public ComboBox.ObjectCollection ComboItems {
    get { return comboBox1.Items; }
}
```

Comment: works great and I accept it :) but why not to use List? and where is the problem? using list will give the user nicer editing list window in designer and He can add items one by one by clicking add button, but be using `string[]` He must add items in a text editor by pressing enter in every line.

Comment: This is the way that string editor works. I'm not sure if there is a built-in `CollectionEditor` which supports string as element.

Comment: Also regarding to your question in the comments, I posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50895911/3110834). I guess, you will find Option 2 useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObjectCollection` for your property and asign it directly to your combobox. This way you are allowed to use the design editor.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public ObjectCollection ComboItems
{
    get
    {
        return comboBox1.Items;
    }
    set
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var i in value)
            comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }
}
```