# What is the best way to edit a List<string> property of custom control at design time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a class derived from `ComboBox` that contains a public `List<string>` property that I want editable at design time.

By default, Visual Studio shows me the same editor that it uses when adding items to a `ListView`, with a pane showing the names of the items on the left and a pane showing the properties of each item on the right.  That's not what I want; I just want to enter a list of strings.

**The editor that pops up when editing the `Items` collection of a `ComboBox` control is what I want.**

I can get that by making the edited property an object of type `StringCollection` instead of an object of type `List<string>`, and then populating my `List<string>` inside the form's `Load` event.  But it seems to me that's more work than I should have to do.

I haven't found a UITypeEditor that will work with a `List<string>` yet, and creating my own looks like too much work.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Edit:  I replaced my `List<string>` with a `StringCollection`, expecting to get the simpler list editor as I did before, but I got the ListView item editor, which does not work.  It complains that there is no default constructor for `System.String`.  I don't understand that error, and people have been complaining about that error appearing in UITypeEditors for at least ten years.

Comment: Show your relevant code.

Comment: [UITypeEditor for `List<string>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50895911/3110834)